Android service is not running anymore (destroyed)
I wrote a foreground service that wait for BroadcastReceiver message and needs to run all the time, suddenly it stopped being listed on the Running services list from Developer options menu
I tried to see if it crashed using logcat -d, but I didn't see anything related to a crash,
I've listed the running services using adb shell dumpsys activity services and I saw it was "destroyed":
  * Destroy ServiceRecord{6b2e72 u0 com.example.app/.sService}
    intent={cmp=com.example.app/.sService}
    packageName=com.example.app
    processName=com.example.app
    baseDir=/data/app/~~wscZKhRzebY3lv8rAajnEg==/com.example.app-4lu3b318SWPa20lceICa4w==/base.apk
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.example.app
    app=null
    allowWhileInUsePermissionInFgs=false
    recentCallingPackage=com.example.app
    recentCallingUid=10715
    allowStartForeground=DENIED
    startForegroundCount=1
    infoAllowStartForeground=null
    createTime=-1d13h45m41s79ms startingBgTimeout=--
    lastActivity=-4h2m40s651ms restartTime=-- createdFromFg=false
    startRequested=false delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=false lastStartId=3
    destroying=true destroyTime=-4h2m40s647ms
    restartCount=0 restartDelay=-4h2m40s742ms nextRestartTime=-4h2m40s742ms crashCount=0

Why it was destroyed or How can I figure out how it why it was destroyed? How to prevent it from being destroyed?
Thanks.
UPDATE - comment related code:
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    ...
    startForeground(102, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));

    return START_STICKY;
}


Have you made any notifications for your foreground service? If you used ServiceCompat.startForeground in onStartCommand of your Service, then you can check if a service is alive or not by checking a notification.

I've added to the question the code that is related to your comment, I do have startForeground called with a notification however I don't understand why is that important because the service is not running according to Running services list so why I need to check for the notification?
